# How to validate a different property that the one changed using IDataErrorInfo with WPF without calling property changed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have 2 textboxs, 1 is for minimum values the other is for maximum values. They cannot call each others propertychange events because that would mess up some other functionality. I have an IDataErrorInfo interface on my view model and when one textbox is validated the other needs to be too.

For example the validation I am looking for is when a min value is larger then a max value there needs to be an error, but this error can be corrected from either textbox and the error for the textbox needs to be removed when this happens. This is easily accomplished by having both the min and max properties call each others property change events but I can not do this as it would break other functionality. I need another way. Any ideas?

```
     #region Implementation of IDataErrorInfo

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets the error message for the property with the given name.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>
            /// The error message for the property. The default is an empty string ("").
            /// </returns>
            /// <param name="columnName">The name of the property whose error message to get. </param>
            public string this[string columnName]
            {
                get
                {
                    string error = null;
                    if (columnName == Reflection.GetPropertyName<ColorPaletteManagerViewModel>(m => m.MaximumColorValue) ||
                        columnName == Reflection.GetPropertyName<ColorPaletteManagerViewModel>(m => m.MinimumColorValue))
                    {
                        error = GetTimeGateError();
                    }
                    _errors[columnName] = error;                              
                    OnPropertyChanged<ColorPaletteManagerViewModel>(m => m.Error);
                    return error;
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets an error message indicating what is wrong with this object.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>
            /// An error message indicating what is wrong with this object. The default is an empty string ("").
            /// </returns>
            public string Error
            {
                get
                {
                    string[] allErrors =
                        _errors.Where(i => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.Value)).Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
                    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allErrors);
                }
            }


            #endregion

    private string GetTimeGateError()
            {
                string error = null;

                if (MinimumColorValue > MaximumColorValue)
                {
                    error = string.Format("The Maximum Color Range Cannot be Less Then The Minimum Color Range");
                }

                return error;
            }

 /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the maximum color value.
        /// </summary>
        public float MaximumColorValue
        {
            get { return _maximumColorValue; } 
            set
            {
                if (_maximumColorValue != value)
                {
                    _maximumColorValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(i => i.MaximumColorValue);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the minimum color value.
        /// </summary>
        public float MinimumColorValue
        {
            get { return _minimumColorValue; }
            set
            {
                if (_minimumColorValue != value)
                {
                    _minimumColorValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(i => i.MinimumColorValue);
                }
            }
        }
```

The xaml:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                            Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

     <TextBox Name="_minColorValue" 
                         Width="55" 
                         Height="22"
                         Grid.Row="1" 
                         Grid.Column="1" 
                         Margin="0,-4,0,0"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=_override, Path=IsChecked}">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="MinimumColorValue" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Delay="500">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <ValidationRules:NumberValidationRule/>
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>

     <TextBox Name="_maxColorValue"
                         Width="55" 
                         Height="22"
                         Margin="0,-4,0,0"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                         IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=_override, Path=IsChecked}"
                         Grid.Column="1" 
                         Grid.Row="2">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="MaximumColorValue" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Delay="500">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <ValidationRules:NumberValidationRule/>
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
```

Comment: If raising property change events breaks other functionality, then I suggest solving _that_ problem instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're targeting .NET 4.5, you could use the [`INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. This interface is pretty much the better version of `IDataErrorInfo` and it includes an `ErrorsChanged` event which tells WPF to reevaluate errors for a given property or for all properties. Then you could simply raise this event as needed.

Unfortunately, this interface is only available since .NET 4.5, so hopefully it's available to you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use attached properties to solve this.

Create an attached property of type TextBox.

Place that attached property on first TextBox and set its value to the value of second TextBox using either x:Reference or Binding ElementName.

Place the same attached property on another TextBox just this time set its value to the reference of first TextBox.

Now each TextBox knows about another. Thats its you won.

Now what you need to do is just to invalidate or change the another TextBox when one has updated the source or has been changed on text input or whatever.

You can do whatever you want now with them since the one will always know about another.

How about this suggestion? I wish I could have posted this a comment but it wont fit in.